# Is it possible to call multi-account AWS API calls without Assuming the IAM Roles & STS?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

The scenario I am trying to implement is to have multiple lambda functions from different AWS Accounts speak to single SNS Topic.

Is there is a possibility make the IAM permission changes at SNS or Role level to have API call directly without having the need to Assume Role, Get STS tokens and then perform the API call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply an SNS Access Control policy on your SNS topics to allow other AWS accounts to work with your SNS topics.

1. Find your SNS topic in the AWS Management Console.
2. Click the topic ARN to view the topic details.
3. From the "Other topic actions" menu, select "Edit topic policy".
4. Either fill in the form in the Basic view, or apply your own policy document using the Advanced view.

An example policy that allows another AWS account to publish to an topic:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"AWSAccountTopicAccess",
    "Statement" :[
        {
            "Sid":"give-1234-publish",
            "Effect":"Allow",           
            "Principal" :{
                "AWS":"111122223333"
             },
            "Action":["sns:Publish"],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:444455556666:MyTopic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_Sns.html

Answer (score 0):

Totally forgot about the SNS Policy where we have the ability to provide the IAM Principle which can be a different role or user or group which can perform API calls.

[image]

[image]